# Seeking online reference available for Fiona and Shapely libraries?

Tags: shapely, references, fiona

Is there an online reference available for the Fiona and Shapely libraries?

I'm thinking a real reference, beside the tutorial-style documentation:

http://toblerity.github.io/shapely/manual.html

http://toblerity.github.io/fiona/manual.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll include [Sphinx autodocs](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc) in the manual for Fiona 1.0 and in the next Shapely manual release. It'll be the very same information you get from help(fiona) and help(shapely) and that's why I've been working hard on docstrings in the code.

Still, narrative docs are the gold standard in my book.

---

See API docs at http://toblerity.github.io/shapely/, http://toblerity.github.io/fiona/